# Not getting any value from EditText in activity

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I know that this might look stupid but still I'm getting frustrated as to why this edittext returns empty value.

```
ImageButton attach = findViewById(R.id.btn_attach);
Button send = findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
EditText message = findViewById(R.id.report_message);

content = message.getText().toString(); // <!-- always null

send.setOnClickListener(v -> {
     if (searchSpinner.getSelectedItems().size() == 0 || content.equals("")) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), content + " > " + categoryList.toString().substring(1, categoryList.toString().length()-1),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     } else {
            if (imageList.size() != 0) {
                doMultipartRequest();
            } else {
                doSendRequest();
            }
    }
});
```

Can't think of any possible cause except that I accidentally clicked on something and it created a duplicate layout and generated a directory in layouts folder with x24 something on its name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get text from your  `EditText` inside `setOnClickListener()`

Try this

```
 send.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        content = message.getText().toString(); // <!-- always null
        if (searchSpinner.getSelectedItems().size() == 0 || content.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    content + " > " +
                            categoryList.toString().substring(1, categoryList.toString().length()-1),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            if (imageList.size() != 0) {
                doMultipartRequest();
            } else {
                doSendRequest();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sir, you are an effin LEGEND! Thank you so much and that was so stupid of me to not realize that getting the value after it was created will not return anything.

Comment: @RichardC.Alvarez Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) if you feel it was useful to you. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:-

```
  ImageButton attach = findViewById(R.id.btn_attach);
  Button send = findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
  EditText message = findViewById(R.id.report_message);


  send.setOnClickListener(v -> {
       if (searchSpinner.getSelectedItems().size() == 0 || message.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
               message.getText().toString()+ " > " +
                       categoryList.toString().substring(1, categoryList.toString().length()-1),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       } else {
            if (imageList.size() != 0) {
                 doMultipartRequest();
            } else {
                 doSendRequest();
                }
            }
      });
```

Hope it will work